# Getting "error: GraphQL schema file should contain a valid GraphQL introspection query result" after apollo schema:download

Tags: graphql, apollo-android

So I set up the graphql server described [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/get-started.html)

Now, I want to generate android queries against this server using apollo android as per [these](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues) instructions.

I've tried different folder configurations for the location of the generated schema against this sample server and no matter what I do I get an error at compile time saying "**GraphQL schema file should contain a valid GraphQL introspection query result**"

Any advice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the solution is to use the **apollo-codegen** cli command and not **apollo schema:download**

Comment: I am having the same issue. How do you use `apollo-codegen`?

Comment: I found an [example](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cli/issues/452) of how to use it: `apollo-codegen download-schema http://localhost:8080/v1alpha1/graphql --output schema.json`